# Frankfurt, Germany storage lockers

Tags: transit

What amount of time, can storage lockers be
Rented for, in Frankfurt, Germany?

Comment: Are you talking about the airport only or the whole city? For the airport it is up to three months (according to the airport website at https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/de/reisen/rund-um-den-flug.detail.suffix.html/article/reisen/gepaeck/aufbewahrung.html)

Comment: Also, _which_ Frankfurt? There are at least two of them in Germany.

Comment: And one of them has two airports (airport Frankfurt and Frankfurt/Hahn)

Comment: @HenningMakholm Technically ambiguous, but almost everybody means Frankfurt am Main (the one with a couple of million people and the huge international airport that's a major European hub) rather than Frankfurt an der Oder (the town of 60k people near the Polish border). Even Wikipedia calls the Frankfurt am Main article "Frankfurt" and just has a little note at the top linking to the Frankfurt an der Oder page.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I'm reacting mainly because the OP seems to think he's _disambiguating_ by tacking comma-Germany on, American-style.

Comment: @HenningMakholm And, in ever practical way, it _does_ disambiguate. Anybody who thinks there's only one Frankfurt in Germany thinks it's a large city in the west, not a town in the east.